# jQuery Click element, then remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with a concept, not sure if my logic is right, it most likely isn't.

I'm hoping to achieve a `div` delete. So I click the `div` and it makes it the active `div` and then I can delete it with the backspace key.

So the flow is -. Click Element - Hit Backspace - `$(this).remove();`,
but not sure how to target the element with a click. I had:

```
$(".spike").live(event, function(del) {
  if (del.keyCode == 8) { $(this).remove();}
});
```

but it doesn't work. (The event is bound to click and ipad touch).

Basically is there any way I can use the click event to target a `div`, maybe to a global variable, that then allows me perform actions to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the idea is to select an item, and save the selection.  Then if the key you want is pressed, delete that item.

Look at this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/GVgEy/5/

Comment: Sorry I should have posted markup, i have lots and lots of .spikes but i slved it by using
    
    var target;
    jQuery.listen( event, '.spike', function(hook){
    target = this.id;

    $(document).keyup(function(del) {
    if (del.keyCode == 8 || g.keyCode == 68 || g.keyCode == 46) { $("#"+target).remove();}
    });

Comment: Then just change `$('.selectable')` to `$('.spike')`, and use your if `if (del.keyCode == 8 || g.keyCode == 68 || g.keyCode == 46)` instead of mine `if (e.which == 0 /*the delete key*/ && CurElement != null)`.  Just make sure to keep the `&& CurElement != null`

Answer (score 0):

change "event" for "click" which is the event you want to handle.

```
$(".spike").live("click", function(del) {
  if (del.keyCode == 8) { $(this).remove();}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I have little to offer but a demo http://jsfiddle.net/E8RaX/1

but the idea is that you assign a class to the active object and then with some prevent defaults you remove any divs with that class.